# RenderAction and ModelState problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
    public ActionResult TestControl()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult TestControl(FormCollection form)
    {
        if(!IsValid(form))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", "Some error");
        }
        return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);;
    }
```

If post have no errors all work fine. But how can I get the current model state in method TestControl() if I add some errors?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and using the ValidationApplicationBlock and a small function I got this.  All with help from referring to David Hayden's site (http://www.davidhayden.com/)

```
if (thread.HasErrors)
                {
                    AddValidationResults(thread.Errors, ViewData.ModelState, ValueProvider);
                    return View(thread);
                }
```

Then inside my BaseController I have:

```
protected static void AddValidationResults(ValidationResults results,
        ModelStateDictionary modelState, IDictionary<string,ValueProviderResult> valueProvider)
{
    foreach (ValidationResult result in results)
    {
        modelState.AddModelError(result.Key,result.Message);
        modelState.SetModelValue(result.Key, valueProvider[result.Key]);
    }
}
```

The key is the second line:

```
modelState.SetModelValue
```

Cheers,

Andrew

Comment: No, I talk about another problemm. 
After ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", "Some error");
I have ModelState.Count == 1
But in TestControl()
I have ModelState.Count == 0, and I understand why but don't know how restore ModelState that was in TestControl(FormCollection form).